# Filter array of objects by comparing their properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I tried to find the highest score on an object in this array, but the result is incorrect.  Should we reset the score to be 0 again? I was trying to put the score variable below the `obj[i.class]` but nothing changed:

```js
function theScore (students) {
  var obj = {};
  score = 0;
  for(i of students){
    if(score < i.score) {
      obj[i.class] = {
        name: i.name,
        score: i.score
      };
    };
  };
  return obj;
};


console.log(theScore([
  {
    name: 'Sara',
    score: 90,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Poyi',
    score: 85,
    class: 'B'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adert',
    score: 74,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Shynta',
    score: 78,
    class: 'B'
  }
]));
```

Desired output:

```
{
A: { 
        name: 'Sara',
        score: 90
   },
B: {
        name: 'Poyi',
        score: 85
   }
}
```

Comment: Not clear if you want the highest overall score, or the highest score for each class.  Looks like it is the latter, but please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code was never actually comparing the the actual object score but to 0 always.

If you really want to use `for in` loop for this you can do something like (with slight changes to your code):

```js
var data = [ { name: 'Sara', score: 90, class: 'A' }, { name: 'Poyi', score: 85, class: 'B' }, { name: 'Adert', score: 74, class: 'A' }, { name: 'Shynta', score: 78, class: 'B' } ]

function theScore (students) {
  var obj = {}
  for(i of students){
    if(!obj[i.class] || obj[i.class].score < i.score) {
      obj[i.class] = {name: i.name, score: i.score}
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(theScore(data))
```

Or you can use `reduce` and solve it like this:

```js
var data = [ { name: 'Sara', score: 90, class: 'A' }, { name: 'Poyi', score: 85, class: 'B' }, { name: 'Adert', score: 74, class: 'A' }, { name: 'Shynta', score: 78, class: 'B' } ]

const maxByClass = (d) => d.reduce((r,{name, score, ...c}) => {
  r[c.class] = r[c.class] ? r[c.class].score > score ? r[c.class] : {name, score} : {name, score}
  return r
}, {})

console.log(maxByClass(data))
```

Since reduce returns an accumulator we simply need to assign the correct object prop based on which one of the 2 classes scores is larger and return.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you massively simplify your function's obj assignment?

```
function theScore (students) {
    var obj = {};
    var score = 0;
    for(i of students){
        if(i.score > score ) { 
            score = i.score;     // Keep track of the highest-score-found-so-far
            obj = i;             // Keep track of the highest scoring object
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: If your original query was correct that "i tried fio find the higest score on this object in array", then, the A-class is the highest score, and it prints the A-class. So it looks like it works to me!

Comment: i want to print class a and b

Answer (score 0):

The score is not being changed after you find the highest score. Change the score to the current score. Thanks. Instead of an object with map, use an object with index(Array). This should work.

```
function theScore (students) {
  var obj = [];
  score = 0;
  for(i of students){
    if(obj.length === 0) {
       obj.push( i );
    } else {
      for( var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++ ){
         if( i.score > obj[x].score ){
             obj.splice( x, 0, i );
             break;
         }
      }
      if( x === obj.length ){
        obj.push(i);
      }
    }
  };
  return obj;
};


console.log(theScore([
  {
    name: 'Sara',
    score: 90,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Poyi',
    score: 85,
    class: 'B'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adert',
    score: 74,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Shynta',
    score: 78,
    class: 'B'
  }
]));
```

Comment: it just print the highest score of class A, i want both class

Comment: It's done, don't forget to mark answer as useful. if it helps.

Comment: i am sorry the ouput is not what i wanted :(

Comment: If you use the answer as described, the array will not get sorted unfortunately.

Comment: Your only option is to use indexed array, associate array will not work. Can't help further. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you don't make any distinction between students' scores in one class versus another class.  You also are not updating the score when you find a higher one, so every student's score (unless it's 0) will be higher than `score` every time your loop runs, and you just end up with the last score in the list.

**EDIT: edited to show how to do this with only one loop**

You need to:

1. Track score for each class
2. Loop over the students
3. Compare that student's score to the class high score for that student's class
4. Update as needed
5. Repeat until done.

```js
function theScore (students) {
  const highScoresByClass = {};
  const scores = {A: 0, B: 0, C: 0};
  for (const student of students){
    const classHighScore = scores[student.class];
    if(classHighScore < student.score) {
      scores[student.class] = student.score;
      highScoresByClass[student.class] = {
        name: student.name,
        score: student.score
      };
    };
  };
  return highScoresByClass;
};


console.log(theScore([
  {
    name: 'Sara',
    score: 90,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Poyi',
    score: 85,
    class: 'B'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adert',
    score: 74,
    class: 'A'
  },
  {
    name: 'Shynta',
    score: 78,
    class: 'B'
  }
]));
```

Comment: cant we dont loop for twice times??

Comment: @PiL I have edited my answer to show how this can be done in a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the already checked `classes`.

A cleaner alternative is using the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to build the desired output.  As you can see, basically, this approach is keeping a track of the previously checked `classes`.

```js
function theScore (students) {
  return students.reduce((a, c) => { 
    a[c.class] = (a[c.class] || (a[c.class] = c));
    if (c.score > a[c.class].score) a[c.class] = c;
    return a;
  }, Object.create(null));
}


console.log(theScore([  {    name: 'Sara',    score: 90,    class: 'A'  },  {    name: 'Poyi',    score: 85,    class: 'B'  },  {    name: 'Adert',    score: 74,    class: 'A'  },  {    name: 'Shynta',    score: 78,    class: 'B'  }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```